# How are minor tributaries determined?

Tags: hydrology, rivers, stream-order

What are the criteria to determine if river A is a major or minor tributary to another River B?

Is stream order the only deciding factor i.e. the highest order is the main stem, one less order is a major tributary and one more lesser order is a minor tributary?

I haven't been able to find any literature on this online.

Comment: Since this is a GIS based stack exchange, it might help if you list what programs you're using or what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

The [method of classification](https://riverrestoration.wikispaces.com/Stream+classification+techniques) (Strahler, Leopold and Wolman, Whiting and Bradley, etc) of order that you choose will determine what is considered a tributary, as not all methods will yield the same results.

Here is a paper on [stream classification in a GIS](http://edna.usgs.gov/Edna/pubs/Stream_Classification_Strategies_Paper.pdf) 
Here is a [jumping off point](http://www.cotf.edu/ete/modules/waterq3/WQassess4b.html) for you about determining stream order, you may also want to try cross posting this to the [earth science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks! I do know about the stream order classifications, however what I do not know is the role it plays if at all in determining MINOR tributaries to a river. As there are people in the field of hydrology use GIS often, that is the reason I posted here. I have also cross posted in other stack exchange.

Comment: How are you classifying the minor tributaries? Do you have information as to the length/width/velocity?

Comment: I am working with the NHD Dataset, so I do not have to calculate the stream order, it is already available. I have determined the tributaries to a river and I am looking to identify if a tributary is a major or minor tributary. I am not looking for a specific GIS solution, just information on what are the properties of a minor tributary.